# C program crashing on scanf

Tags: c

I got a simple project from university I was working on,, it was about Super Market Billing System. So I started working on but every time I give input as a user the program crashes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void welcome();
void list();
int main()
{
welcome();
}
void welcome()
{
    int ch;
    printf("\t\t\tSuper Market\n");
    printf("Make Your choice\n");
    printf("1.Go Shopping\n2.Check Bill\n3.Check Offers");
    scanf("%d",ch);
    switch (ch)
    {
        case 1: list();
        default : printf("wrong choice");
    }
}
void list()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("1.Item First");
    getch();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `scanf("%d",ch);` --> `scanf("%d", &ch);` Also need `break;` last of case section.

Comment: I feel stupid now. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: You're also gonna want `break;`s inside your `switch`. And a `return 0;` at the end of `main` would be considered good practice.

Comment: @arun483 I've rolled back your `[Resolved]` edit. [Please don't do that here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101). Instead, mark the answer that helped you most as "accepted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to give `&`

convert this

```
scanf("%d",ch);
```

to this

```
scanf("%d",&ch);
```

**Suggestion**:

you need to use `break` in your `case`. Otherwise, control flow will "fall through" into succeeding `case`s

```
case 1: 
   list();
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a pointer of the integer to scanf.

```
scanf("%d", &ch);
```

This needs to be done since function calls in C are 'pass by value', but you want to change the value of the variable `ch` by the input from the user. So you pass it by giving a reference to scanf, thereby allowing it to change the value.

Comment: Explanation of why it was down-voted would be appreciated.